# rspec + factory model testing nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, nested-attributes

I have a rails4 app with rspec + factory_girl. I would like to test the validation that makes sure the product has at least one feature, competition, usecase and industry. The first 3 must belong to a product, but industry can exist on its own. I haven't tried to put industry in the test yet since I can't even make work the first 3.

I tried the approach below in which I create a product factory that has product_feature, product_competition and product_usecase. For some reason it's not working.

Do I use the right approach? If so, what's wrong with my code?

```
1) Product nested attribute validation has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: expect(create(:product_with_nested_attrs)).to be_valid

     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: You have to choose at least 1 industry., You must have at least 1 product feature., You must name at least 1 competition., You must describe at least 1 usecase.
```

product.rb (UPDATED)

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :industry_products, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :product
has_many :industries, through: :industry_products #industry exists without product; connected with has_many thru association
has_many :product_features, dependent: :destroy
has_many :product_competitions, dependent: :destroy
has_many :product_usecases, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :industry_products, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_features, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_competitions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_usecases, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

#UPDATE

validate :product_features_limit #Also have it for product_usecases and product_competititons

def product_features_limit
  if self.product_features.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).count > 10
    self.errors.add :base, "You can't have more than 10 features."
  elsif self.product_features.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).count < 1
    self.errors.add :base, "You must have at least 1 product feature."
  end
end
```

factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :product_competititon do
    competitor { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
    differentiator { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    product
  end

  factory :product_feature do
    feature { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    product
  end

  factory :product_usecase do
    example { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    detail { Fakert::Lorem.paragraph }
    product
  end

  factory :product do
    name { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
    company { Faker::Company.name }
    website { 'https://example.com' }
    oneliner { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    user

    factory :product_with_nested_attrs do
      transient do
        nested_attrs_count 1
      end
      after(:create) do |product, evaluator|
        create_list(:product_feature, evaluator.nested_attrs_count, product: product)
        create_list(:product_competititon, evaluator.nested_attrs_count, product: product)
        create_list(:product_usecase, evaluator.nested_attrs_count, product: product)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

product_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe Product, type: :model do

  describe "nested attribute validation" do

    it "has a valid factory" do
      expect(create(:product_with_nested_attrs).to be_valid
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Not featureful enough to do a full answer: you don't have to do a create_list, you can do something like: `product.product_features << create(:product_feature, product: product)`  wrap an `x.times { }` block around it if you need some number of them.

Comment: Jim, what do you mean by not featureful enough? Could you tell me why it would work in that case and why it's not working with this code here?

Comment: Usually I back up my answers with references to the API docs.  In this case, I felt it was 'quick and dirty'

Answer (score 1):

There is a gem `shoulda` (https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) which let you test `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (validations and associations as well) directly with one single matcher. But if you prefer to test the behavior(what) rather then implementation(how), you can do something like follows ...

Just as what I mentioned before ([setting up objects for model testing with factory_girl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36610591/232710)), I would remove associations from factories first.

Factories

```
factory :product_competititon do
  competitor { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
  differentiator { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
end

factory :product_feature do
  feature { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
end

factory :product_usecase do
  example { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  detail { Fakert::Lorem.paragraph }
end

factory :product do
  name { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
  company { Faker::Company.name }
  website { 'https://example.com' }
  oneliner { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
end
```

Specs

```
RSpec.describe Product, type: :model do

  describe "validation" do
    let(:user) { create(:user) }

    it "should be valid if a product has at least one competition, feature, usecase and industry" do
      attr = attributes_for(:project).merge({
        user_id: user.id,
        product_competitions: [attributes_for(:project_competition)],
        product_features: [attributes_for(:project_feature)],
        product_usecases: [attributes_for(:project_usecase)],
        product_industries: [attributes_for(:industry)],
      })
      expect(Product.new(attr)).to be_valid
    end

    it "should be invalid if no competition is given" do
      attr = attributes_for(:project).merge({
        user_id: user.id,
        product_features: [attributes_for(:project_feature)],
        product_usecases: [attributes_for(:project_usecase)],
        product_industries: [attributes_for(:industry)],
      })
      expect(Product.new(attr)).to be_invalid
    end

    it "should be invalid if no feature is given" do
      attr = attributes_for(:project).merge({
        user_id: user.id,
        product_competitions: [attributes_for(:project_competition)],
        product_usecases: [attributes_for(:project_usecase)],
        product_industries: [attributes_for(:industry)],
      })
      expect(Product.new(attr)).to be_invalid
    end

    # ... similar test cases for usecase and industry validation ...

  end
end
```

Comment: Sibevin, I'm using `shoulda-matchers` with the nested attrs. Isn't that just testing if there is `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is set in the model?  With this code I try to test if the created product has at least one `product_feature`, `product_usecase`, etc. Updated my `product.rb` with the validator.

Comment: Sibevin, pls also check my prev comment. So I played around with this code and getting `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: ProductFeature(#70333990300640) expected, got Hash(#70333940263240)` error. So I guess the product which is not created yet  should be passed to the `attributes_for(:product_feature, product: #this product)`, but no clue how. I feel it's like a chicken egg problem since they have to be created at once. So If I try to create product first then getting at least 1 feature must be created error and if try to create the feature then getting product must be defined error.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar Your first comment is right, so I prefer to test the behavior rather than the implementation. (Although the shoulda use the similar way to implement its matcher).

Comment: @SzilardMagyar I found there is typo in my answer: `Project.build` should be `Project.new`, maybe this is a problem. All I try to do in my answer is to simulate the object new process, just like a form submission. `attributes_for` is a method (provided by factory_girl) to create an attribute hash based on the factory. If `attributes_for` is not working, try to change it to `build`.