# rspec model spec let vs factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm starting out with testing and it's not exactly clear when I should use `let`.

Should I use `let` in the following model testing for lazy loading or since the data is bit different in every test I can keep it as it is? As I've seen in some examples it's way more important for controller testing as the `:task` would be the same for each action test.

model spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Task, type: :model do

  describe "model validations" do

    it "has a valid factory" do
      expect(build(:task)).to be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without executor" do
      expect(build(:task, executor_id: nil)).not_to be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without assigner" do
      expect(build(:task, assigner_id: nil)).not_to be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without content" do
      expect(build(:task, content: nil)).not_to be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without deadline" do
      expect(build(:task, deadline: nil)).not_to be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid with deadline in the past" do
      expect(build(:task, deadline:  Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now - 1, DateTime.now - 2))).not_to be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task do
    content { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    deadline { Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now + 2, DateTime.now + 3) }
    association :executor, factory: :user
    association :assigner, factory: :user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefits of `let` come from tests that aren't of the form you use above.  Imagine this group:

```
context "completing tasks" do
  let(:completing_a_task){ task.complete }
  context "that aren't due yet" do
    let(:task){ create(:not_due_task) }
    it "should not send an email" do
       expect( TaskMailer ).not_to receive(:deliver_message)
       expect{ completing_a_task }.not_to raise_error
    end
  end
  context "overdue" do
    let(:task){ create(:overdue_task) }
    it "should send an email" do
       expect( TaskMailer ).to receive(:deliver_message)
       expect{ completing_a_task }.not_to raise_error
    end
  end
end
```

By allowing for late binding, you can make minimal changes but provide maximal coverage.  The more collaborators you need in order to set up the appropriate behavior needed for your tests, the more likely you are to benefit from `let`.  While it's try that you don't particularly need to drive for DRY in your test suite, huge setup blocks for your tests are a smell, and the `let` technique is a great tool to help fight for clarity and simplicity even when your domain presents complexity.  My own example includes no collaborators still, but hopefully the concept is still clear enough.

Comment: Jim, can you also copy this code with factory to exactly see the difference?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar factories accomplish a much different goal.  A factory's job is to provision domain objects (and perhaps persist them to the database).  This stanza of tests you write above is essentially identical to those I write for every meaningful model in one of my apps.  My `let` statements frequently contain either factory outputs themselves, or domain methods invoked on objects created by a factory.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Jim, for instance I don't see you using the `task` from `let(:task){ create(:not_due_task) }` or from `let(:task){ create(:overdue_task) }, so don't really get your example.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar ah, I see!  The test does contain `completing_a_task`, which is itself defined in a `let`.  Because of the late binding nature of let, when the example is run, the not due task receives the `.complete` invocation inside of `completing_a_task`.  This is the essence of the answer; you are not required to sequentially set things up, rather compose and tweak as you go through your contexts.  Give it a try yourself and see.

Comment: Thanks Jim! Could you also take a look at this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569195/rspec-factory-model-testing-nested-attributes?

Comment: Agreed that huge setup blocks are a smell, but it's an application logic smell, not a test smell. DRYing things up essentially hides the smell, but does not address the underlying issue. One of the reasons I advise against `let` is exactly what has happened here - it can be hard to follow, evidenced by OP not understanding how it all came together. Check this out for some reading on the topic: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/lets-not. Nothing inherently wrong with `let`, but it's easier to misuse than it is to use correctly. Good to see different opinions though.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the source!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest keeping it how you have it and not using a `let`. Don't worry about DRYing up your tests. They don't interact with each other, and so you don't run into the issues you would with code duplication in application logic.

For what it's worth, you can use the `shoulda-matchers` gem to accomplish what you've got there: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

```
describe Task do
  describe "validations" do
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:content) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:deadline) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Nick, I'm using shoulda matchers just didn't copy the code here. As far as I know those are only checking the existence of the validation. With this code I wanna make sure my factory and object works fine.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar `shoulda-matchers` for the most part checks against values, not for the presence of the validation. For example, if you used `validate_presence_of`, you could skip the built-in Rails presence validator and recreate it on your own (`errors.add(:content, "can't be blank") if content.blank?`). and the shoulda matcher would work as expected. You can see in the source that it checks against actual blank values: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_presence_of_matcher.rb