# setting up objects for model testing with factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'd like to test the scopes below but don't know hot to setup test objects properly. I don't even know if I should create those in factory with some associations or using let/local vars.

task.rb

```
belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"

scope :completed, -> { where.not(completed_at: nil) }
scope :uncompleted, -> { where(completed_at: nil) }
scope :alltasks, -> (u) { where('executor_id = ? OR assigner_id = ?', u.id, u.id) }
scope :between, -> (assigner_id, executor_id) do
  where("(tasks.assigner_id = ? AND tasks.executor_id = ?) OR (tasks.assigner_id = ? AND tasks.executor_id = ?)", assigner_id, executor_id, executor_id, assigner_id)
end
```

factories

```
factory :task do
  content { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  deadline { Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now + 2, DateTime.now + 3) }
  association :executor, factory: :user
  association :assigner, factory: :user #I guess this is not right
end

factory :user do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "example#{n}@gmail.com" }
  password 'example0000'
  password_confirmation 'example0000'
  new_chat_notification { Faker::Number.between(0, 10) }
  new_other_notification { Faker::Number.between(0, 10) } 
end
```

task_spec.rb

```
describe Task do

  .....

  describe "scopes" do

    #I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SETUP THE TEST OBJECTS PROPERLY
    let(:uncompleted_task) { create(:task) }
    let(:completed_task) { create(:task, completed_at: DateTime.now - 2) }
    let(:user) { create(:user) 

    let(:task_1) { create(:task, executor_id: user.id, assigner_id: (user.id + 1)) }
    let(:task_2) { create(:task, assigner_id: user.id, executor_id: (user.id + 1) }
    let(:task_3) { create(:task, assigner_id: user.id, executor_id: (user.id + 2) }

    it "completed" do
      expect(completed_task).to eq(Task.completed.first)
    end

    it "uncompleted" do
      expect(uncompleted_task).to eq(Task.uncompleted.last)
    end

    it "alltasks" do

    end

    it "between" do
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are seeing? eg what error messages do you get when you try to run this code?

Comment: With this code nothing, but I deleted the code from the `alltasks` because of  PG user already exists problem. As you see for `alltasks` and `between` I have to create a few tasks with a given `user_id` to check if those return only the matching tasks. So my problem is setting up proper user and task objects for the methods. AS I mentioned don't even know what approach to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I prefer NOT to setup associations in factories due to the following reasons:

1. If there are associations in a factory, every time an object is created/built, the associated objects are created at the same time. It means many database accesses are triggered even you just 'build' an object. The more associations you use, the more time is required to run a test.
2. You should setup associations in the test when you really need it. If you setup associations in a factory, it means the 'given' part of given-when-then process is hidden from the test. It becomes more difficult to find what is going wrong when a test is failed.

To test a scope, you should follow some best practices:

1. Make your scopes as simple as possible, it is harder to test complicated scopes. For example, you should break down your `between` scope to small ones if needed.
2. Use the minimal objects to test the scope because we need to create records in database to test a scope. The database access slows down the testing and we should reduce the object creation as possible. For most cases, two objects (positive and negative) should be enough to test a simple scope.

By the way, you may misunderstand the usage of `let`, the object defined with let is created only when the object is called in test cases. In your original specs, no tasks or users are created because none of them is called. To do what you want, you should use `before` block instead.

For your example, I would create factories and specs below:

Factories

```
factory :task do
  content { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  deadline { Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now + 2, DateTime.now + 3) }
end

factory :user do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "example#{n}@gmail.com" }
  sequence(:password) { |n| "password#{n}" }
  password_confirmation { password }
  new_chat_notification { Faker::Number.between(0, 10) }
  new_other_notification { Faker::Number.between(0, 10) }
end
```

Specs

```
describe Task do
  # ...
  describe "scopes" do
    let(:executor) { create(:user) }
    let(:assigner) { create(:user) }

    describe "completeness related" do
      before(:example) do
        @uncompleted_task = create(:task, executor: executor, assigner: assigner)
        @completed_task = create(:task, executor: executor, assigner: assigner, completed_at: DateTime.now - 2))
      end

      it "completed" do
        expect(Task.completed).to include(@completed_task)
        expect(Task.completed).not_to include(@uncompleted_task)
      end

      it "uncompleted" do
        expect(Task.uncompleted).to include(@uncompleted_task)
        expect(Task.uncompleted).not_to include(@completed_task)
      end
    end

    it "alltasks" do
      me = create(:user)
      owned_task = create(:task, executor: me, assigner: assigner)
      assigned_task = create(:task, executor: executor, assigner: me)
      not_my_task = create(:task, executor: executor, assigner: assigner)
      expect(Task.alltasks(me)).to include(owned_task, assigned_task)
      expect(Task.alltasks(me)).not_to include(not_my_task)
    end

    it "between" do
      # ... (there should be as last 5 tasks to create)...
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

There are more details and hits about how to write tests in the book "Rails 4 Test Prescriptions - Build a Healthy Codebase by Noel Rappin", and it is worth reading if you are interested.

Comment: I've read Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec and the first half of Rails 4 Test Prescriptions, but don't really get the exact role of `let`. Do you have a nice article, that compares let + factory + before? You know the problem is all the sources tell something different. I don't see why I can't use `let`. I mean I use the `create` in the `let` definition, so object will persist, once the test calls the certain test. As for your example, you use it for user but not for task, which I don't understand why. Could you elaborate your answer a bit more or point the an amazing source about `let`? Thx

Comment: `let` is just like a declaration, `let(:executor) { create(:user) }` doesn't create any user records in database until `@uncompleted_task = create(:task, executor: executor, assigner: assigner)` is executed, i.e., `let(:executor)` create a user record only when `executor` is used(called). You can get `let` examples on the official doc (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) as well.

Comment: Keep reading this book and you will learn all you want to know ;-)

Comment: Thanks Sibevin! Could you also take a look at this issue?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569195/rspec-factory-model-testing-nested-attributes. I guess I've got similar problems there.